# Caching of dynamic stylesheets in CMSMS

Tags: css, caching, content-management-system, smarty

I'm using CMS Made Simple. I'm trying to include conditional Smarty code in my `css` stylesheet.

```
[[if $raduno eq '1']]
  [[assign var='bgcolor' value='#bc3516']] /* red */
[[else]]
  [[assign var='bgcolor' value='#f3c127']] /* yellow */
[[/if]]

body {
    background-color:  [[$bgcolor]];
    ...
}
```

The code seems to be working (I get a red vs. yellow background depending on the value of `raduno`). However, caching of `css` stylesheets seems to interfere with this approach. The background color selected on the first page visited after clearing the CMSMS server cache is the one I also get on all subsequently visited pages, regardless of the value of variable `raduno`.

Is it possible to cache the stylesheet depending on the value of a variable? (If so, automatically or manually?)

The problem is currently resolved by having two separate stylesheets. However, this makes maintainance difficult. Also, disabling the cache is not an option here --- the template using the two stylesheets is used for the whole site.

I am using CMSMS version 1.10.3.  I realize that upgrading *might* help, but I haven't found any indications that this is the case in the changelogs.  (And *my* version is installed on opensourcecms.com!)

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to do this would be to avoid caching the stylesheets, which would not be a good idea. The simplest workaround would be to use inline css and Smarty, or do the swap with jquery.